# Difference to send on sight with compact in laravel

Tags: laravel

what is the difference when sending data to the view of the two ways I get the same result

```
return view ('admin.about.index', compact ('about'));

return view ('admin.about.index') -> with (compact ('aboutsImage'));
```

Comment: There is no difference—they’re just two different ways of passing the same data to a view in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

`compact` method support multiple variable to pass,
`with` method supports only one variable to pass, also you can declare it in method and still using it multiple times>

```
...->with('about','aboutImage')->with('text','aboutText')...
```

if you already have variables filled and need to pass more than two, compact mode will be easier.

Comment: `with()` actually accepts an array as well, so you can also pass more than one variable this way as well

Comment: yes but only one.. even if you have an array of arrays as varialbe.. still being one variable.

Answer (score 0):

To [pass data to a view](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#passing-data-to-views) you can do both:

```php
return view('greetings', ['admin' => $user, 'store' => $store]);
```

or

```php
return view('greetings')->with('admin', $user)->with('store', $store);
// sugared
return view('greetings')->withAdmin($user)->withStore($store);
```

With these two methods, you still receive your object in the view under the variable names that you define.

On the other hand, when you do [`compact()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) it will create an associative array of the object/collection that you pass it in. It also let's you add multiple variables there.